# Hibernate: get persisted state of dirty entity

Tags: java, hibernate

Taking following code:

```
MyEntity e = dao.getEntity(1);
e.setProp1(someVal);
e.setProp2(otherVal);

MyEntity eOld = dao.getEntity(1);
```

If I do it like this then e will get updated (because Hibernate detected it is dirty) and eOld will have the same property values (prop1, prop2) a e. Is there a way to get the persisted state of this dirty entity (as it is in the database)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I may already have found the solution myself...

I had already tried evicting eOld but that doesn't make since, I need to evict e before retrieving eOld and after the compare (for auditing) reattach (merge) e to the session again.
It seems to work in any case.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
<property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false" />
```

Or alternative use `detach` and re-attach when ready to persist.

```
dao.detach(e);
...
e.setProp1("AnotherVal"); //not propatated to the database
dao.merge(cat);  // update
```

Comment: tx but I was hoping for something less drastic :-)

Comment: Use detach and merge when you're ready to propagate as alternative.

Comment: Yes, that was my first approach but I abandoned it because in this way I have to evict (detach) in my controller instead of my service (since the properties are set in the controller). But I may have to go back to this if post-evicting in the service doesn't work out.